# Microsoft.Data.SQLite: Library e_sqlite3 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite, iis

My ASP.NET MVC (.Net Framework 4.7.2) web app using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 5.0.2 crashes (both in debug IIS Express, and app.publish on local IIS in Windows 10) at line:

```
SqliteConnection dbConn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
```

The exception thrown :

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at sqliteTest.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in C:\Users\FaqeerHussain\source\repos\sqliteTest\sqliteTest\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 16
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Inner Exception 2:
Exception: Library e_sqlite3 not found
```

e_sqlite3.dll is already in `bin\runtimes\win-x64\native` and `bin\runtimes\win-x86\native`. Tried copying x86/x64 e_sqlite3.dll to root `bin` folder but error remains. What should I do to get Microsoft.Data.Sqlite working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the package of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is not compatible with the version of .Net Framework. You can try to change the version of NuGet of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite to 2.2.0 to run normally.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I found that the e_sqlite3.dll is located at **runtimes\win-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll**.
So I created those folders and added the e_sqlite3.dll in the native folder. After that it worked!

Answer (score 6):

Dump `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` in favor of `System.Data.Sqlite`. It supports version 3.38 databases with upserts an other perks and has no such issues. I did and never looked back.

The difference will be in the casing of the names:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Instead of:

```
SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
SqliteConnection
SqliteCommand
SqliteTransaction
SqliteType.Text
```

you will use, respectively:

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
SQLiteConnection
SQLiteCommand
SQLiteTransaction
DbType.String etc
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19396) that hasn't been fixed yet.

I was referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 library that was using SQLite, from a .NET Framework 4.8 project. I changed library to also target .NET 4.8 as a workaround since it wasn't used by any other implementation of .NET. I had to change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>` in my SQLite project.

Comment: This solved the problem. A little sad, but it'll do. "e_sqlite3.dll" was added to the output folder after I set it to framework 4.8. And a "runtimes" folder was created in the project too.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` depends on `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3`, and `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3` depends on `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3`, where `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3` does not have actual DLL as it provides native binary directly. So when I hit this issue I found that `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3` NuGet and it's build targets are not present in my `csproj` upon installation. So when project is being build  by VS or MSBuild both of them are not aware that `e_sqlite3` native binary has to be copied into `bin` folder during the build.

I did solve the issue by adding targets manually into `csproj`:

```
<Project>

  ...

  <Import Project="..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.5\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.5\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.5\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.5\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets'))" />
  </Target>

  ...

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and it was caused by mixing of the `packages.config` and `PackageReference`. (I'm working on some old legacy software right now) I Right-Clicked the `packages.config` and selected `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference` and it fixed the issue where it wasn't able to find the e_sqlite3.dll when calling `SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();` Additionally, I no longer needed to  call `SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();` so I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

My ASP.NET (.Net Framework 4.7) web app in which I used Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 5.0.10 gives :

> Exception: Library e_sqlite3 not found

I removed dependency library of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core, SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3, SQLitePCLRaw.core,
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3, SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl, etc., from package folder. I added Microsoft.Data.Sqlite version 6.0.0 along with its dependencies. My app is working now. I only used this library to read SpatiaLite database.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back to version of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite that used to work for my older projects (4.7.2 and pre) to 1.0.0. And I did check: the platform subfolders and DLL's were there.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error in NUnit 2 GUI for .NET Framework 4.7.2 test library  using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 5.0.0. Found xUnit solution [here](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/389), which is to disable shadow copy.

Answer (score 0):

For a `Maui` multiplatform app make sure your have the following in your project file (update to actual version):

```
    <ItemGroup>    
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still there in ALL the latest releases! I cannot believe this is still going on maybe 5 years after the issue was first reported.

I fiddled with this for an age before I got it working. The simple solution was eventually found.

Build the project for AnyCPU

Copy e_sqlite3.dll from release\x86 folder to the same folder as the main executable

App then runs, no error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, may not be the same issue for everyone.
Look at your project file, and search for e_sqlite3.
You should see a line like this:

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.8\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.8\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets')" />
```

This tells Visual Studio where to get the targets file, which in turn determines where to put the e_sqlite file.

In my case, this was the wrong location, it was going one more directory up than it needed to. I changed ....\ to ..\ and everything was found and the file was put into the right location.

The correct project file line should be:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.8\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.2.1.8\buildTransitive\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets')" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you downloaded Microsoft.Data.Sqlite using NuGet: Use the directory
\Users"UserName".nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3"Version"\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll
Where "Version" is not e_sqlite3.dll version, but Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
For e_sqlite3.dll version, execute cmd.CommandText = "select sqlite_version();"

Comment: This is poorly formatted, and very difficult to understand what you're trying to say; you should consult the markdown formatting guide: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help